# Failing to save form's data to different models

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to django and I have the following code snippet. What I am trying to do here is get some form field's value, compare it to a string and if matches found then save the value in a different Model.

```
def log_name_insert(request):
    if 'logged_in' in request.session:
        if request.session['logged_in'] is True:
            form = LogEntryForm(request.POST or None)
            phaseform = PhaseNameForm(request.POST or None)
            testForm = TestTypeForm(request.POST or None)
            priorityForm = PriorityNameForm(request.POST or None)
            frequencyForm = FrequencyNameForm(request.POST or None)
            statusForm = StatusNameForm(request.POST or None)
            defectSeverityForm = DefectSeverityNameForm(request.POST or None)
            causeCategoryForm = CauseCategoryNameForm(request.POST or None)
            leakagePhaseForm = LeakagePhaseNameForm(request.POST or None)
            testStatusForm = TestStatusNameForm(request.POST or None)
            # print(form)
            if form.is_valid() and phaseform.is_valid() and testForm.is_valid() and priorityForm.is_valid() and frequencyForm.is_valid() and defectSeverityForm.is_valid() and causeCategoryForm.is_valid() and leakagePhaseForm.is_valid() and testStatusForm.is_valid() and statusForm.is_valid():
                if LogEntry.objects.filter(log_name_add=request.POST['log_name_add']).exists():
                    print("entry found")
                else:
                    form.save()
                    print(form.cleaned_data['log_name'])
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Phase":
                        print(form.cleaned_data['log_name'])
                        obj = PhaseList()
                        phaseform.cleaned_data['phase_name'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.phase_name = phaseform.cleaned_data['phase_name']
                        obj.save()
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Test Type":
                        obj = TestTypeList()
                        testForm.cleaned_data['test_type'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.test_type = testForm.cleaned_data['test_type']
                        obj.save()
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Priority":
                        obj = PriorityList()
                        priorityForm.cleaned_data['priority_name'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.priority_name = priorityForm.cleaned_data['priority_name']
                        obj.save()
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Frequency":
                        obj = FrequencyList()
                        frequencyForm.cleaned_data['frequency_name'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.frequency_name = frequencyForm.cleaned_data['frequency_name']
                        obj.save()
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Status":
                        obj = StatusList()
                        statusForm.cleaned_data['status_name'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.status_name = statusForm.cleaned_data['status_name']
                        obj.save()
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Defect Severity":
                        obj = DefectSeverityList()
                        defectSeverityForm.cleaned_data['defect_severity_name'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.defect_severity_name = defectSeverityForm.cleaned_data['defect_severity_name']
                        obj.save()
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Cauese Category":
                        obj = CauseCategoryList()
                        causeCategoryForm.cleaned_data['cause_category_name'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.cause_category_name = causeCategoryForm.cleaned_data['cause_category_name']
                        obj.save()
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Leakage Phase":
                        obj = LeakagePhaseList()
                        leakagePhaseForm.cleaned_data['leakage_phase_name'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.leakage_phase_name = leakagePhaseForm.cleaned_data['leakage_phase_name']
                        obj.save()
                    if form.cleaned_data['log_name'] == "Test Status":
                        obj = TestStatusList()
                        testStatusForm.cleaned_data['test_status_name'] = form.cleaned_data['log_name_add']
                        obj.test_status_name = testStatusForm.cleaned_data['test_status_name']
                        obj.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Data Saved')
                    return redirect('defectlog:log_name_list')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Wrong data in form')
                return redirect('defectlog:log_name_insert')
        else:
            return redirect('defectlog:login')
```

Now, whenever I try to execute it, my page stops loading because of too many redirections. Is it because I am trying to validate too many forms at a time ? Also I think I am comparing the values in a wrong way. Please help me if I am doing anything wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When executing the view the first time, you load it with a GET request. As a result, you create all your forms with None as first argument, so forms are unbound and the following test

```
if form.is_valid() and phaseform.is_valid() and [...]:
```

is False. Then you go in the else branch:

```
messages.error(request, 'Wrong data in form')
return redirect('defectlog:log_name_insert')
```

so you return a HTTP redirect response to the browser. Your browser follow this redirection to the same view, and re-execute the same code, fall to the same redirection, again, and again, and again. But your Internet browser detect this case and stop the infinite loop quickly. That's why you get a "too many redirections" error.